# C# Function calls using Services

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am debugging a code that uses Services to execute Stored Procedures. The code is as follows:

```
void serviceClient_EvaluateScoresCompleted(object sender, EvaluateScoresCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        this.GenerateExcelFiles(e.Result as System.Data.DataSet);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(e.Error.Message);
        Response.Write(e.Error.InnerException);
        Response.Write(e.Error.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

And the button click code is as follows:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsultantShares> consultantShareList = this.GetConsultantShareList();


    if (consultantShareList == null)
    {
        Response.Write("Please fix the Metioned Errors to Continue");
        return;
    }

    CIServiceClient serviceClient = new CIServiceClient();
    serviceClient.EvaluateScoresAsync(consultantShareList, this.ddlTargetProject.SelectedValue.Split(new char[] { '-' })[0], this.txtWorkclass.Text, this.ddlTargetProject.SelectedValue.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1]);
    serviceClient.EvaluateScoresCompleted += new EventHandler<EvaluateScoresCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient_EvaluateScoresCompleted);
}
```

There is no stored procedure named Evaluate Scores or Evaluate Scores Completed. The problem is with the `e.Result as System.Data.DataSet` above, as in the data in the DataSet is not correct and I want to see where this is calculated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

unless CIServiceClient is also developed by your group you likely won't be able to debug it. That's part of the reason to use web services, you keep the logic tucked away so the consumer has no need to see it.

Comment: I see the ICIService that has this definition

    [OperationContract]
        System.Data.DataSet EvaluateScores(List<ConsultantShares> consultantShares, string targetProjectId, string projectWorkClass,string type);

Comment: you have the method signature, but not the actual definition correct?